# User.Identity.Name = "" but user is authenticated. possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=userLevel.aspx");
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       if (Request.Form["action"] == "getUserData")
        {
            string nm = User.Identity.Name;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(nm);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

the user loged in and he is authenticated, but when I check for his name I get ""
I try to get the user name using a jquery ajax, and I return the data to the ajax

**update:**
a look at my immediate window (while in a break point) when a user named moria is logedin

```
**User.Identity**
{System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
[System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity]: {System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
AuthenticationType: "Forms"
**IsAuthenticated: true**
**Name: ""**

**Membership.GetUser()**
**null**

**Membership.GetUser("moria")**
{moria}
Comment: null
CreationDate: {23/02/2016 01:10:08}
Email: "orders.gca@gmail.com"
IsApproved: true
IsLockedOut: false
IsOnline: false
LastActivityDate: {24/02/2016 03:21:08}
LastLockoutDate: {01/01/1754 02:00:00}
LastLoginDate: {24/02/2016 03:21:08}
LastPasswordChangedDate: {23/02/2016 01:10:08}
PasswordQuestion: "1"
ProviderName: "MySqlMembershipProvider"
ProviderUserKey: {ff589472-e852-4049-8803-6d22740414ee}
UserName: "moria"
```

Comment: You should test with _Request.IsAnthenticated_ to know authentication process is correct...

Comment: Possible answer http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/874837/Why-User-Identity-IsAuthenticated-always-false

Comment: Aymeric - in my case User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return true, the problem is the User.Identity.Name is ""

Comment: Could you post the code of jQuery Ajax?

Comment: I can post the code but it is not relevant, because the same problem occures when I do as described here https://forums.asp.net/p/2086189/6025356.aspx?Re+userName+is+empty+after+successful+login

Answer (score 1):

Taking from ADreNaLiNe-DJ's answer and adding in the ability to redirect back to the calling page, you would add this to the Global.asax file:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginUrl = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Login", "Account") ?? "";
        if (!this.Request.IsAuthenticated && !this.Request.Path.Contains(loginUrl))
        {
            Response.Redirect(loginUrl + "?ReturnUrl=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check authentication earlier in the pipeline.
Add this code in your Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Request.IsAuthenticated && !this.Request.Path.Contains("login.aspx"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=userLevel.aspx");
    }
}
```

You check authentication for all pages/requests in 1 unique place.

So when you are in the *Page_Load*, you are sure to be logged in and authenticated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["action"] == "getUserData")
    {
        string nm = User.Identity.Name;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(nm);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: If i will check authentication in global.asax.cs, how can I direct the user to the page he came from, after he will login? if I check in a specific page i can attach to the login.aspx a querystring with current page url.

Comment: when I  use vb I check it in Page_PreLoad event of each page but in c# I dont know how to create this event

Comment: If you use the code i gave you for checking authentication: it will redirect users to the login if they are not authenticated or if they are accessing login page. Otherwise, the request continues normally. So there's nothing to do to _"direct the user to the page he came from"_

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. but it doesn't solve my problem, I even tried to disable the ajax call and to out put to a server side textbox the User.Identity.Authenticated.ToString + User.Identity.Name and I get just the word True without the userName